# Parsing one sentence at a time with the Stanford Parser

Tags: perl

I have a text file with about 6000 sentences, each on their own line.
I want to use the Stanford Parser in the Windows command prompt to parse the sentences. However, I need to send one sentence at a time to the parser (because the sentences are aligned with the sentences of another file).

I want to write a Perl wrapper to:
Write one sentence from the input file to a temp file, send the temp file to the parser, parse the one sentence, write the parsed output to an output file, and write the output file to my big output file, ParsedOutput.txt.

This is probable a very basic thing to do, but I’m stuck. Any help or guidance would really be appreciated.

Thank you! :)

Edited:
This is what I've tried so far:

```
open (ENGDATA, "<1tot1660.txt");
open (ENGDATAOUT, ">temp.txt");
while (<ENGDATA>)
{
my $line = $_;
chomp $line;    
while ($line)
    {
    my @OneLine = $line;
    print ENGDATAOUT "$OneLine[0]\n";
    shift(@OneLine);
    }
}
```

I was thinking: Have each line as an element in an array, write the 0th element to the temp output file, and then remove the first element  (so that it won't accidentally be used again).
I am basically stuck with the whole program, but for the moment: at writing one line (at a time) to the temp output file.

**EDIT!** (again.. Thanks, TLP and amon! :) )
This is what I eventually did:

```
open (ENGDATA, "<Testing10.txt");
open (ENGDATAOUT, ">TempOut.txt");
open (PARSEDOUT, ">ParsedOutput.txt");

while (<ENGDATA>)    
{
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    my $inputfilename = $line;
    print ENGDATAOUT "$line\n";

    my $parsecommand = qx(java -mx150m -cp "*;" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat "penn,typedDependencies" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz $inputfilename);

    print PARSEDOUT "$parsecommand\n";
}
```

I now get this error for every word in my input:

> Parsing file: superior
>   edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor: Could not open path superior
>   Parsed file: superior [0 sentences].

What's this all about? Does anyone know and could you maybe help, please?
Thanks!

Comment: 1. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
2. Can we see some code?
3. Where *exactly* are you stuck?
4. You know about `open` and `qx()` or backticks?

Comment: Please see the edited version of my question. :) Unfortunately I don't know anything about qx() or backticks..

Comment: There is an [NLP::StanfordParser](https://metacpan.org/module/NLP::StanfordParser) module that may help.  Its documentation is lacking so I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: @BillRuppert I took a look at that module… It wouldn't be *that hard* to use after half an hour of experimenting, but it has an overwhelming list of dependencies… I understand `Moose` and `Carp` (best practice!), but `Dancer` (a web framework? wtf?) and especially `Inline::Java` are not only non-Core, but a bit over the top. And I dislike `common::sense` ;-) **tl;dr:** Don't use it.

Comment: You should include more information about how your Stanford parser program works. The optimal way to solve this is: 1. Use a module, 2. Open a pipe to your parser and write/read each line sequentially, 3. Worst case scenario, do as you do now, print to a temp file and start a new process for each line in the input file.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your help. :) I followed some of your advice and eventually figured out what to do. However, I get this error message for every word in my input: "could not find path". 
I will post a complete explanation in my question stated above.

Comment: Your variable juggling `@oneline = $line`, `$oneline[0]` and `shift @oneline` is completely and utterly redundant. You might as well use `$line` all the way through.

Comment: In addition to @TLPs comment I'd like to point out, that you are quoting the content inside the `qx`. As `qx` is a quote-like operator itself, you should remove the quotes and the escaping of the quotes inside. Currently you are trying to execute a program called `java -mx150…` not `java` with arguments `-mx150m`…

Comment: Thanks, I made the appropriate changes. I still get the same error, though.. :(

Comment: Why are you using Perl for this anyway? Sounds like about four lines of shell script.

Comment: I take it one uses a shell script in Linux?
I'm doing a university project that requires the use of Perl. And Perl and a bit of Java is the only programming language I know. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the heck of it, a shell script version.

```
while read -r; do
    printf '%s\n' "$REPLY" >tmp
    parser -input tmp -output tmp2
    cat tmp2
done <input >output
rm tmp tmp2
```

If the parser can be made to read from standard input and write results to standard output, this can be simplified significantly. On Linux you could use `/dev/fd/0` and `/dev/fd/1` if it insists on file name arguments.

```
printf '%s\n' "$REPLY" |
parser -input /dev/fd/0 -output /dev/fd/1
```

and do away with the temporary files completely.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Your code seems to be copying the file `1tot1160.txt` to `temp.txt`, introducing some very interesting syntax on the way ;-)

I would do it like this:

1. Declare all the filenames in one place:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   use strict; use warnings;
   my $BigInFile     = ...;
   my $BigOutFile    = ...;
   my $ParserInFile  = ...;
   my $ParserOutFile = ...;
   ```
2. Open the Big files, and start looping over the input:

   ```
   open my $BigIn,  '<', $BigInFile  or die "Cant open $BigInFile";
   open my $BigOut, '>', $BigOutFile or die "Cant open $BigOutFile";
   while (defined(my $line = <$BigIn>)) {
       print $BigOut doStanford($line);
   }
   ```

   We put each line of the Big Input File into `$line` while it is defined (read: while we don't have the EOF). Then we print the output of the subroutine `doStanford` to the Big Output File, assuming it already has an ending newline. If not, feel free to write the code to append it.
3. Write the subroutine `doStanford`. We take a line, write it to the Temp file, invoke the programm, and read the other Temp File and return the contents:

   ```
   sub doStanford {
       my ($line) = @_; # unpack arguments

       # open the firstfile:
       open my $StanfordIn, '>', $ParserInFile
         or die "Couldn't open $ParserInFile";
       print $StanfordIn $line; # already has newline
       close $StanfordIn;

       # do the call to the parser. I don't know the interface
       # so I assume it is "parser --in INFILE --out OUTFILE"
       my $returnValue = system("parser",
         "--in", $ParserInFile,
         "--out", $ParserOutFile);
       if ($returnValue != 0) {
           # an error occured
           die "The Parser exited with return value $?: $!.\n";
       }

       # read in the other file, and return:
       open my $StanfordOut, '<', $ParserOutFile
         or die "Couldn't open $ParserOutFile";
       my $parsed = <$StanfordOut>; # we only want the first line
       return $parsed;
       # implicit close $StanfordOut
   }
   ```

There *may* ;-) be some typos in here, so better write it yourself.

I did some Error Handling for the `system` call for good style. An exit value of 0 indicates success, non-zero exit values (especially -1) indicate some error or abnormal termination.

If the Parser can output to STDOUT instead of a file, you can execute the command inside `qx{}`:

```
my $parsed = qx{parser --in INFILE};
```

That way we can't do error handling, but we don't need extra files.

Inside the `system` call, I split the arguments into a list. If we supplied one string only, the Command Line would split it at every space; undesirable if our pathnames include spaces as well. The way I did this, they are safe.

If you can use a module for this, use the module. It is safer and easier.

#### Edits

- The return value of `system` isn't actually the exit status of the command called. The return value is just 0 when the command succeeded, and true on error. The exit status is the value of the expression `$? >> 8`. `$!` may be set to a reason.

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote. I'm not sure this is the right answer but amon put a lot of effort into this, and yet somebody had downvoted.